# Fastest way to cut a pandas time-series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Looking for the fastest way to cut a timeseries ... for example just taking the values that are more recent than a certain index.

I've found two commonly used methods:

```
df = original_series.truncate(before=example_time)
```

and

```
df = original_series[example_time:]
```

Which one is faster (for large time-series > 10**6 values) ?

Comment: Why don't you try it with `%timeit`?

Comment: If you provide some sample data, maybe someone bored will play around with `perfplot` or `timeit` to give you some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

This usually depends on what your dataframe index is, throwing a random DataFrame of 10^7 values into timeit we get the following.

From a performance standpoint in truncation more inefficient as pandas is optimized for integer based indexing via numpy.

```
Truncate: 
62.6 ms ± 3.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Bracket Indexing:
54.1 µs ± 4.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

ILoc:
69.5 µs ± 4.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Loc:
92 µs ± 5.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Ix (which is deprecated):
110 µs ± 8.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**EDIT** This is all on pandas 0.24.2, back in the 0.14-0.18 versions loc performance was much much worse